# Install4j: Silent updater exits on start

Tags: install4j

I am running my installer in silent mode (`-q` option).
After starting, the installer quits. The `error.log` shows the entry:

```
"The application is running. Please close instances and run this installer again".
```

However, there is no other instance of the installer running.

**Note** - The installer is launched in the Windows local system account.

Comment: Try to add a "Check for running processes" action to the installer and run it in GUI mode. It will show you which processed a blocking the installation.

Comment: If the installer is run in GUI (i.e. run without -q option) mode it goes ahead without any issue. When run in the silent mode it fails. The action it fails is - "Load a response file". All actions before this particular one have succeeded.

Comment: The message that you refer to is printed while checking whether an installed launcher or another installer application are still running. That is not done by the "Load a response file" action. How did you determine that actions before that one have been executed?

Comment: Added the "Check for running processes" action now. Able to determine that it is one of our processes which is running and blocking the upgrade. Question is what is the difference the various close strategies allowed for this action?

Comment: Soft close is like clicking the close button on a window, terminate is like killing the process in the task manager

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the exact same issue with an updater installer being run in unattended (silent) mode and launched from a Windows service. I discovered that there were two reasons for the updater failing to complete:

1. The unattended mode installer was being invoked with arguments `-q -wait 20` (these are the defaults when generating an updater application using the install4j UI). The `-wait` argument causes the installer to wait for running applications to close *before* progressing to the stage where the Welcome screen would normally be shown in an interactive install. It does not attempt to close them itself. If the applications don't disappear within 20 seconds, the installer exits at this early stage with the error.log message "The application is running. Please close instances and run this installer again". (In interactive mode the user would be shown a screen at this stage asking them to close the running applications.)

   (**Note:** `-wait` only seems to check for the presence of application processes (user launched apps, UIs etc). Installed services that are running are not considered a blocker, probably because they are automatically stopped as part of the Install files action.)

   I had already added actions later in my installer to close down the application processes before installing the update, but the `-wait` argument was not allowing it to progress that far. I removed the argument from the "Set installer arguments" action in the updater app and this allowed the installer to progress beyond the welcome phase.
2. The 'Check for running processes' action, using a Close strategy of 'Soft close immediately', failed to close any user-launched applications running (UI applications in my case) when the installer was launched from the Windows service. This in turn caused the unattended update to fail due to locking issues overwriting the installed files.

   However using the Close strategy of 'Terminate immediately' **did** allow the service account to successfully kill the running applications and allowed the installation to complete.

   I ended up using a sequence of "Stop a service", "Check for running processes (soft close)" (which works when the installer is run in interactive mode by a user), then "Check for running processes (Terminate immediately)" at the start of the Installation section to cover all bases.